# Quota doesn't report any warning even if the soft limit is crossed. Only reports the warning for hard limit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, warnings, quota

I installed linux quota package and enabled disc quotas on cloud machine. Linux version is *Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-112-generic x86_64)*. Machine is a part of domain.

Contents of *fstab*:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs / ext4 usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0 1
/dev/vdb        /data   ext4 usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0 0 0
```

Result of the *sudo repquota -ugsCv /data*:

```
Report for user quotas on device /dev/vdb
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days

                        Space limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
root      --  20329M      0K      0K           476k     0     0
[username1] --   2172M      0K      0K           221k     0     0
systemd-network --    228K      0K      0K             57     0     0
[username2] --   7104K      0K      0K            212     0     0
systemd-resolve --   4054M      0K      0K          49404     0     0
[username3]  +-    201M    200M    220M  6days       4     0     0
```

I see, that quotas work and soft limit is reached by my *username3*, but I **don't receive any warnings** in the console when  perform any file operations, till I reach hard limit, and then I see:

```
cp: error writing '/data/testquota/testfile2': Disk quota exceeded
```

**How can I fix this behavior or bug, I want warnings to be shown in the console, or this is impossible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer from quota developer | creator, Jan Kara:**

*What you see is just a message from cp(1) that it got EDQUOT error from a write(2) syscall. The warnings about the softlimit (and the hardlimit) being reached are printed by the kernel to the controlling terminal of the process and you don't seem to see any of those. Now the question is what is the controlling terminal of the cp(1) process in your cloud machine and why can't you see the message. You can find controlling terminal e.g. from ps(1) output (TTY column). Also find these lines in /proc/config.gz from your machine:*

```
CONFIG_QUOTA
CONFIG_QUOTA_NETLINK_INTERFACE
CONFIG_PRINT_QUOTA_WARNING
```

*If CONFIG_PRINT_QUOTA_WARNING is not set , that your kernel is compiled without support for printing quota warnings to the console. If you have CONFIG_QUOTA_NETLINK_INTERFACE=y, that the kernel is compiled with CONFIG_QUOTA_NETLINK_INTERFACE so you can run quota_nld daemon (from quota-tools package) to print messages to console instead.*

So I ran `sudo quota_nld -b` and put it in the cron and all users began to receive warnings.